# Is it possible to have a first-pass callback for any exception thrown in the application?

Tags: c#, exception

I'm working on a legacy code base which has a lot of exception swallowing. A lot of `try` blocks with hundreds of lines and a single `catch` block swallowing everything and simply logging the exception message.

Is it possible to install some sort of global first-pass exception handler to the entire application so I can proper log the stack trace of each exception before passing it to those gigantic try/catch blocks? That's only to avoid rewriting every `catch` block to include the stack trace in the logs.